Is installing deadgrep fron MELPA still possible?
I would like to try using deadgrep (in order to use ripgrep from Emacs).
The step "Install deadgrep from MELPA (do M-x package-install RET deadgrep within Emacs 25.1 or later)" (from https://github.com/Wilfred/deadgrep/blob/master/README.md#installation ).
does not work for me; I'm told "No match". Is it no longer possible to install deadgrep from MELPA ?
The alternative installation method given on that page "or copy it into your ~/.emacs.d." sounds a little scary to an inexperienced user like me ... I'm not even sure what "it" refers to exactly...

Please show the content of package-archives variable. Btw, the package is available on Melpa.

Oh, and did you execute package-refresh-contents prior trying to install it?

Thank you so much. Melpa is not included in package-archives. I've tried now to add it in various ways (including adding ;; packages
(when (>= emacs-major-version 24)
(require 'package)
(package-initialize)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/") t)
) as suggested here link but mysteriously to me this doesn't seem to change the value....

That means you need to add it. See the code in my answer.

Oh, just to clarify why you need that: Melpa is technically an unofficial repo, which is why Emacs by default doesn't contain its address. The official one is Elpa (note the missing M), but presumably Melpa has easier process of posting packages (I think so, but I might be wrong; I didn't have experience of posting a package), so people are typically posting there.

The package is available on Melpa.
While theoretically, of course, anything possible up to some quantum states messing with your network communication; but practically there might be exactly two reasons you have the problem: you either didn't add Melpa to your package-archives variable, or you didn't make Emacs fetch the data from Melpa prior to attempting installation.
To demonstrate:

Given this minimal .emacs file:
(package-initialize)
;; Note: make sure the address has prefix `https://` Otherwise Emacs will assume
;; it is a filepath.
(push '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")
      package-archives)


Evaluate M-x package-refresh-contents
Evaluate M-x package-install deadgrep

The deadgrep gets successfully installed.

How very helpful of you, thank you. I have added the code to ~/.emacs.d/init.el which I thought was the equivalent. It did not add Melpa. I have now made a .emacs file in my home directory with the code. That too doesn't seem to add Melpa to package-archives . I'm on Macos running GNU Emacs 29.1, and really mystified. But thank you again for such prompt and, I'm sure, good advice!

You don't have to create ~/.emacs if you're using a ~/.emacs.d/init.el. Can you please show your ~/.emacs.d/init.el code?

Just to clarify: if you created .emacs it will likely conflict with init.el. You need exactly one init file, doesn't matter which one.

Thank you! I've deleted the  ~/.emacs.d/init.el file; the ~/.emacs is at the moment very simple indeed, namely:
(Set-frame-font "Menlo 26" nil t)
(set-message-beep 'silent)
(setq-default xref-search-program ‘ugrep)
(package-initialize)
(push '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")
package-archives)
The font is being set at the size specified, so the .emacs file does seem to be being read but ... Melpa still doesn't seem to be in package-archives ... Thank you for all your help!

and sorry, it's not "Set-frame-font" but "set-frame-font" ....

Well, I am seeing you have a unicode singular quote (as opposed to the usual one) in ‘ugrep. Idk if it's due to you rewriting the code to the comment manually or is it an actual error in the file. Either way, please try switching to *Messages* buffer after loading Emacs with this file and see if it has any error messages there.

Oh, btw, another problem is you need the Melpa address to be prefixed with https://, see my code for an example. I just tried your way without https:// and it didn't work for me, so you do need to specify that part.

Thank you again! Changed the quote and I saw also that the set-message-beep command was generating some kind of an error so I've cancelled that for the moment and ... now Melpa is in package-archives and I've been able to install deadgrep! Thanks a million for your patient and unbelievably quick help...

Np! Idk about set-message-beep, but if you wanted to disable beeping sounds, you'd need (setq ring-bell-function 'ignore). Nvm me rewriting the comment a few times, it does work
